# How to pass a two dimensional array parameter of a function as parameter of an inner function

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array, arguments

I found out how to pass a two dimensional array as a parameter to a function and then do operations with its elements. My case however is more specific: A function has a two-dimensional array as a parameter, and its body contains another function, the parameter of which is that same array.
Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const double FLT_EPSILON=0.3;
bool areEqual(double a, double b, double epsilon)
{
    return abs(a - b) <= ((abs(a) > abs(b) ? abs(b) : abs(a)) * epsilon);
}
double LineSUM(int N, double matrix[][N], int line)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + matrix[line][i];
    }
    return sum;
}
double RowSUM(int N, double matrix[][N], int row)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + matrix[i][row];
    }
    return sum;
}
//some other  irrelevant code
bool matrixIsMagicalSquare(int N, double matrix [N][N])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (!areEqual(LineSUM(N, matrix, i), LineSUM(N, matrix, j), FLT_EPSILON))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    //some other code
}
int main()
{
    int N=0;
    cin>>N;
    double martrix[N][N];
    //code to enter the elements of the array
    cout<<matrixIsMagicalSquare(N, matrix);
}
```

Trying to compile the code returns "No matching function for call to '`LineSUM`'" and the same error for `RowSUM`. The reason for this message is that the parameter of `Line/RowSUM` (the array called `matrix`) apparently is not the same type as in its definition. What am I doing wrong? Please excuse me for any inaccuracies in the question. English is not my native language.

Comment: Note that changing `bool matrixIsMagicalSquare(int N, double matrix [N][N])` to `bool matrixIsMagicalSquare(int N, double matrix [][N])` or `bool matrixIsMagicalSquare(int N, double (&matrix)[][N])` didn't work for me.

Comment: The code above is not legal C++. In C++ arrays bounds must be *compile time constants* **not** variables. Wherever you have been learning about C++ it hasn't been telling you the truth.

Comment: In C++ if you want an array with a variable size you use a `std::vector`.

Comment: @john. Oops, I missed that. When I put that code in the post, I erased some of it and the declaration of N was removed by accident. I will edit the post.

Comment: Thanks, but the main point is that your code is not legal in C++. This is not legal C++ `int N=0; cin>>N; double martrix[N][N];`

Comment: @john. Using vectors in this task is forbidden. Moreover, I know by default that the size of the matrix will be NxN. If I change the parameters from [][N] to [N][N], will it work?

Comment: I have no idea (really I don't) you are using non-standard features of C++. It depends on your compiler.

Comment: @john Are you refering to the rule that the size of the array must be a constant value and N is not a constant?

Comment: Yes, and `N` must be a compile time constant, not just any constant. The compiler must know the size of any array, if it doesn't its not legal C++. (it might be legal C, but that's a different language).

Comment: If you cannot use a `std::vector`  and want to be compliant with the standard, then you will have to play with `new` and create `double **` matrices

Comment: @DanielHalachev `using namespace std;` is missing.

Comment: Well, on Visual Studio the code cannot run but it uses the VC compiler, but it runs on GCC

Comment: @Damien. If I put the code of LineSUM directly inside of the bool function, will I be able to go around the problem?

Comment: @DanielHalachev `double martrix[N][N];`  You declared `martrix`   and you are using `matrix`.  Typing mistake

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula Thank you for pointing that out. The mistakes you mentioned accured because I erased/edited some of the code here after pasting it in the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your function headers. The parameter value within the brackets is illegal. Change your code to work with array pointers instead:

```
double LineSUM(int N, double** matrix, int line)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + matrix[line][i];
    }
    return sum;
}

double RowSUM(int N, double** matrix, int row)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + matrix[i][row];
    }
    return sum;
}

//some other  irrelevant code
bool matrixIsMagicalSquare(int N, double** matrix)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (!areEqual(LineSUM(N, matrix, i), LineSUM(N, matrix, j), FLT_EPSILON))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    //some other code
}

int main()
{
    cin>>N;
    double** matrix;
    // You will now have to initialize matrix on the heap because
    // you cannot initialize an array on the stack with a non-const size.

    //code to enter the elements of the array
    cout<<matrixIsMagicalSquare(N, matrix);
}
```